# Html.BeginForm in a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a block of code that uses the Html.BeginForm to submit a value from textbox to controller.  When I put this in a View, it works fine. That is, the controller's action method is called. However, when I place this block of code inside a partial view that will get rendered in the View, the controller's action never gets called.

Not sure if this is the usual behavior or if I am missing something...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestAction", "Home",  FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formId" }))
{<table>
   <tr>
        <td>Data Date</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("date")</td>
    </tr>    
   <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input id="btnRun" type="submit"  value="submit" /></td>
   </tr>
```

}

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult TestAction(string date)
 {
     [doing something......]
     return View();
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you run this what is the actual rendered HTML in the browser ?

Comment: The html shows all the controls in the View along with the form tags of the partial view: <form action="/Home/TestAction" id="formId" method="post">.....</form>

Comment: `/Home/TradeFeed` is not the same as `/Home/TestAction`. Or you were just trying to illustrate the situation ?

Comment: I was illustrating the situation. Corrected the example. Thanks for noting it.  By the way, there is no html.BeginForm in the View.  Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Can you post the view code, since what you have here is correct I presume the issue is in the parent view.

Comment: Dimitar, thanks it was my View.  I've been at this all morning and it was due to stupid mistake.  I had two buttons named the same on both the view and partial view.  I had javascript code in the view to do something else.  Sorry for wasting your time.  Let me know how I can give you points for leading me to my blunder.

Comment: Nah don't worry about it ;) glad I could help ! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically `@Html.BeginForm()` renders the `<form>` tag's action to point back to the route details that got it here.  Thus in partial views, you're actually rendering back to the outer page.  (Yeah, mind-bending.)  If you want to specifically direct the form post to a particular route, add additional parameters to the `@Html.BeginForm()`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.108).aspx