# Why does my PartialView render outside the form tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view that displays an HTML table of "Room" objects.  Each Room is a row (which is a PartialView) in the table.

The view contains this code:

```
<table>

    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.Partial("_roomPartial", item)
        }
    }

</table>
```

Model is an `IEnumerable<Room>`, and _roomPartial is an HTML row containing the properties of a Room.

For some reason, the HTML of the Partial renders after the closing form tag (despite being inside the using block):

```
<form action="/Room/Index" method="post"></form>
<tr>
    ...some boring markup...
</tr>
```

Other things I tried to make this work:

- Used `Html.RenderPartial("_roomPartial", item);` instead of `@Html.Partial`.
- Moved the `using (Html.BeginForm())` block inside the PartialView

I got the same HTML results each time.

Why does the Partial render outside the form tag?  And how can I get it to render properly?

---

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PatientAssigner.Models.Room>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isOccupied)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.patientComplexityLevel)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.Partial("_roomPartial", item)
    }
}
</table>
```

_roomPartial:

```
@model PatientAssigner.Models.Room

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(room => room.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(room => room.ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(room => room.isOccupied)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(room => room.isOccupied)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(room => room.patientComplexityLevel,
                                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(PatientAssigner.Models.PatientComplexityLevel)),
                                                    Model.patientComplexityLevel),
                                                    "")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(room => room.patientComplexityLevel)
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" id="saveBtn" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if a form tag can be a child of a table or tr tag?

Comment: @lucuma Wow!  No I have not.  I'll check on that.

Comment: I'm willing to bet it must be inside a `td`...

Comment: What are the contents of the `_roomPartial` view? Does it start with `<tr><td>` and end with </td></tr>`?

Comment: @lucuma Hmmm, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) says that a form tag can be in any element that accepts flow content (and `<table>` does accept flow content).

Comment: @DavidG You are correct, it starts and ends with those tags.  I can add the full view code, I just didn't want to clutter the post (since it's pretty basic HTML).  I'd be glad to add it, though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369576/mvc-partial-view-with-controller-ajax-how-do-i-ge-the-partial-controller-to-g?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676229/html-beginform-in-a-partial-view, both make reference to having to pass data through the additional parameters of `BeginForm`, and talk about how partials aren't rendered through the controller but to the outer page. Or something. I actually have no idea what you're talking about; this is all Greek to me -- but maybe this is helpful info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10301073/616460 also has some key info about making sure `BeginForm` and `Partial` all use the same controller.

Comment: @JasonC Thanks for the links!  Unfortunately, those seem to mostly have to do with routing issues (making sure the form is posting back to the right controller, etc).  My form tag looks okay, it just renders out of order.  Or at least it closes to early.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`form` tags are not valid between `table` and `tr` tags. I suggest changing your view to not have the `tr` or `td` tags and do this outside:

```
<table>

    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {
        <tr><td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.Partial("_roomPartial", item)
        }
        </td></tr>
    }

</table>
```

If you need to have a `form` for every row but want your `input`s spread across cells, your only option is to have nested tables like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>cell1</td>
            <td>cell2</td>
            <td>cell3</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>cell1</td>
            <td>cell2</td>
            <td>cell3</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Minor fix - I missed off an `@`

Comment: Well, I can't really take the `<td>` out of the partial.  Or at least, it seems weird to do.  Because then there's invalid markup in the partial (there's more than one td).

Comment: That doesn't matter, Razor doesn't care about HTML markup. The only other way is to also put the `BeginForm` inside your partial.

Comment: Okay, I gave this a shot, but it doesn't really change the behavior.  If I take the `<tr>` and the first `<td>` out of the partial, and transplant them in the view, I just wind up with an extra `<td>` tag, that contains an empty form (in the rendered HTML).

Comment: I also tried moving the using block into the PartialView, with the same results.

Comment: Then I think we need to see your view, I've tried it at my end and it's fine.

Comment: Sure, no problem.  I've added it to the end of the question.

Comment: Oh, you only want a single `form`, not one per item?

Comment: No, I do want one per item.  That's why the BeginForm block is inside the loop.

Comment: Although, you've definitely got me on the right track here.  I didn't consider that my invalid markup might cause the Razor Engine to choke / behave erratically.

Comment: OK, then my answer is still valid. Razor won't choke on it, though the browser might have trouble.

Comment: Strange, it's not working on my end.  It gets a little closer, I guess.  It wraps the contents of the first `<td>` in form tags.

Comment: I think I see your problem now, you want a `form` for each table row with `input`s spread across multiple cells. I'm afraid you can't do that.

Comment: Your best option is to have a nested table for each row, I will update my answer...

Comment: Thanks for the info, DavidG.  This looks like it would work.  I probably just go with a different approach (this has been silly from the beginning).  I was just curious about the strange behavior.

Comment: I feel really foolish, but on closer inspection, the HTML actually is like what I specified.  It's the Chrome Inspector that gets all messed up trying to display the unexpected structure (so it prematurely "closes" the form tag).  What I see in View Page Source is right (wrapping the entire tr in a form tag), but the Inspector shows something else entirely (form tag immediately closing, and tr tag starting after it).